# VLC no video displayed for DVD when non-admin

Tags: windows-vista, dvd, vlc-media-player, non-admin

When I play a DVD using VLC in Vista as a non-admin user, I don't get any video displayed.  The DVD plays normally when running as an administrator.

Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed in the latest (1.0.3) version of VLC.